# The method is undefined for the type Class<capture#3-of ? extends Command>

Tags: java, generics, casting, abstract-class, subclass

I have the abstract class

```
package main;

public abstract class Command {
    protected final String key;

    public Command(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public abstract void function(String[] args);
    public abstract void help();
}
```

But when I try to call the method `function(String[] args)`, albeit in a confusing and overly complicated way, problems ensue.

---

```
Class<? extends Command> x = (Class<? extends Command>) Class.forName(
        "main.Commands$" +
        String.valueOf(command.toCharArray()[0]).toUpperCase() +
        command.substring(1).toLowerCase()
);

x.function(args);
```

Gives me the error `The method function(String[]) is undefined for the type Class<capture#3-of ? extends Command>`

I alternatively tried the following:

```
Command x = (Command) Class.forName(
        "main.Commands$" +
        String.valueOf(command.toCharArray([0]).toUpperCase() +
        command.substring(1).toLowerCase()
);
```

But that just gave me `Cannot cast from Class<capture#1-of ?> to Command`.

I apologize in advance for my poor naming.

Comment: I think we're going to need to see the implementation class, too.

Comment: Where are you calling `function()` ? I can't see it.

Comment: @DavidWallace apologies, edited

Comment: OK, so you're getting a `Class` object, then you're trying to call a method on it that's defined in the `Command` class.  A `Class` is not a `Command`.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: OK, I retract my last question.  I see what you're trying to do.  Quick question - do the various subclasses of `Command` have no-arg constructors?  Or do they require you to pass in the `key`?  If it's the former, then @MichaelAnderson's answer is correct.  If it's the latter, you'll need something slightly more complex, which I can post if you need it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Class.forName` is returning a `Class<?>` object, not a `Command`. You need to create the Command using one of the constructors in the `Class<?>` object.

```
Class<Command> klass = (Class<Command>) Class.forName(
    "main.Commands " +
    String.valueOf(command.toCharArray([0]).toUpperCase() +
    command.substring(1).toLowerCase()
);

Command x = klass.newInstance();
```

Alternatively you can use the `klass.getConstructor(...)` method